# Fastest way to calculate maximum pixel gray value in the 8-adjacency of every pixel

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, loops, image-processing

I want to calculate the maximum pixel gray value in the 8-adjacency of every pixel in a given image.

I am using the below code to achieve it in C.

```
        for(x = 0;x<row;x++){
            for(y = 0;y<col;y++){
                maxpixel = INT_MIN;
                if((x-1)>=0 && (y-1)>=0){
                    maxpixel = max(maxpixel,img[x-1][y-1]);
                }
                if((x-1)>=0){
                    maxpixel = max(maxpixel,img[x-1][y]);
                }
                if((x-1)>=0 && (y+1)<col){
                    maxpixel = max(maxpixel,img[x-1][y+1]);
                }
                if((y+1)<m){
                    maxpixel = max(maxpixel,img[x][y+1]);
                }
                if((x+1)<row && (y+1) <col){
                    maxpixel = max(maxpixel,img[x+1][y+1]);
                }
                if((x+1)<row){
                    maxpixel = max(maxpixel,img[x+1][y]);
                }
                if((x+1)<row && (y-1)>=0){
                    maxpixel = max(maxpixel,img[x+1][y-1]);
                }
                if((y-1)>=0){
                    maxpixel = max(maxpixel,img[x][y-1]);
                }
                // do some other constant time operation.
            }
        }
```

The above code works as expected. However, this seems like very iterative as slow.

Is there any scope of improvement to increase the speed ?

Comment: One way to increase the speed would be to make the first row and the last row, the first column and the last column, special cases. Then you don't need to test the bounds for the typical pixel with 8 neighbours. Is `max` a function or a macro? Make sure it is inline.

Comment: When you calculate the maximum of three pixels in a row (for example 1/3, 2/3, 3/3) then you can use that value for the maximum pixel calculation of 2/2 and 2/4, which saves you some calculations. Maybe this can serve you as a start for further optimizations

Comment: Is this a one time pass though `img[]` or will the happen many times?

Comment: @beaker yes it was a typo. Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use a big [if-else](/questions/tagged/if-else) statement, instead of several [if](/questions/tagged/if) statements. That way, you won't have to evaluate all the statements, let alone the branch prediction.

This should be a good way to start optimizing your code. Other than that, you can post in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for more. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Between any two adjacent pixels there are six shared expressions suggesting that there is potential of about 66% speed increase.

In practise one can calculate maxima separately in vertical and horizontal directions:

```
 for (i=0;i<h-2;i++) {
     for (j=0;j<w;j++)
        M[j] = max3(img[i][j], img[i+1][j], img[i+2]);
     for (j=0;j<w-2;j++)
         Out[i][j] = max4(M[j], img[i][j+1], img[i+2][j+1], M[j+2];
}
```

This completely avoids out-of-range testing and reduces comparisons slightly. The resulting image is of course 2 pixels shorter in each direction.

Answer (score 0):

You have eight special cases that happen more or less, and sometimes those cases can coincide, in cases you have only one row or only one column or both:

```
[]====+=====================================+====[]
|| UL | Upper row                           | UR ||
++----+-------------------------------------+----++
|| Le | Main block                          | Ri ||
|| ft |                                     | gh ||
||  c |                                     | t  ||
|| ol |                                     | co ||
||    |                                     | l  ||
||    |                                     |    ||
++----+-------------------------------------+----++
|| LL | Lower row                           | LR ||
[]====+=====================================+====[]
```

I should use a different loop for each, so you know a priory what cells are accessible and don't have to do any tests.  You have to consider the special cases you can have in case the array has only one row or one column, but that's all.

I'll assume you have an array of array pointers, as you don't tell, but it simplifies the access to the matrix cells with the `[]` operator.

```
inline int max2(int a, int b) 
{ 
    return a > b ? a : b; 
}
inline int max3(int a, int b, int c) 
{ 
    return max2(max2(a, b), c); 
}
inline int max4(int a, int b, int c, int d) 
{ 
    return max2(max2(a, b), max2(c, d)); 
}
inline int max6(
        int a, int b, int c, 
        int d, int e, int f)
{
    return max2(max3(a, b, c), max3(d, e, f));
}
inline int max9(
        int a, int b, int c, 
        int d, int e, int f, 
        int g, int h, int i)
{
    return max3(max3(a, b, c), max3(d, e, f), max3(g, h, i));
}

void max_value(int **in, int **out, int rows, int cols)
{
    if (rows > 1) {
        /* to avoid many calculations */
        int rows_1 = rows - 1, rows_2 = rows - 2;

        if (cols > 1) { /* cols > 1 && rows > 1 */
            int cols_1 = cols - 1, cols_2 = cols - 2;

            /* first consider the four corners */
            /* UL */
            out[0][0] = max4(
                 in[0][0],          in[0][1], 
                 in[1][0],          in[1][1]);

            /* LR */
            out[rows_1][cols_1] = max4(
                 in[rows_2][cols_2],in[rows_2][cols_1],
                 in[rows_1][cols_2],in[rows_1][cols_1]);

            /* LL */
            out[rows_1][0] = max4(
                 in[rows_2][0],     in[rows_2][1],
                 in[rows_1][0],     in[rows_1][1]);

            /* UR */
            out[0][cols_1] = max4(
                 in[0][cols_2],     in[1][cols_2],
                 in[0][cols_1],     in[1][cols_1]);

            /* next the two side columns */
            for(row = 1; row < rows_1; row++) {
                /* left */
                out[row][0] = max6(
                 in[row-1][0],      in[row-1][1],
                 in[row][0],        in[row][1],
                 in[row+1][0],      in[row+1][1]); 

                /* right */
                out[row][cols_1] = max6(
                 in[row-1][cols_2], in[row-1][cols_1],
                 in[row][cols_2],   in[row][cols_1],
                 in[row+1][cols_2], in[row+1][cols_1]);
            } /* for */

            /* ... and the top/bottom rows */
            for(col = 1; col < cols_1; col++) {
                /* top */
                out[0][col] = max6(
                 in[0][col-1], in[0][col], in[0][col+1],
                 in[1][col-1], in[0][col], in[0][col+1]);
                /* bottom */
                out[row_1][col] = max6(
                 in[row_2][col-1], in[row_2][col], in[row_2][col+1],
                 in[row_1][col-1], in[row_1][col], in[row_1][col+1]);
            } /* for */

            /* and finally, the main block */
            for(row=1; row < row_1; row++) {
                for(col=1; col < col_1; col++) {
                    out[row][col] = max9(
                     in[row-1][col-1],in[row-1][col],in[row-1][col+1],
                     in[row][col-1],in[row][col],in[row][col+1],
                     in[row+1][col-1],in[row+1][col],in[row+1][col+1]);
                } /* for */
            } /* for */
        } else { /* rows > 1 && cols == 1 */
            /* we collapsed to three zones in one column */  
            /* UL == UR */
            out[0][0] = max2(
                    in[0][0],
                    in[1][0]);

            /* LL == LR */
            out[row_1][0] = max2(
                    in[row_2][0],
                    in[row_1][0]);

            /* main block */
            for(row = 1; row < rows_1; row++) {
                out[row][0] = max3(
                    in[row-1][0],
                    in[row][0],
                    in[row+1][0]);
            } /* for */
        } /* if */
    } else { /* rows == 1 */
        /* the nine zones collapse to three */
        if (cols > 1) {
            /* UL == LL */
            out[0][0] = max2(in[0][0], in[0][1]);
            /* UR == LR */
            out[0][col_1] = max2(in[0][col_2], in[0][col_1]);
            /* the main part */
            for(col=1; col < cols_1; col++)
                out[0][col] = max3(in[0][col-1],in[0][col],in[0][col+1]);
            } /* for */
        } else { /* rows == 1 && cols == 1 */
            /* ... or one */
            out[0][0] = in[0][0];
        }
    } /* if */
} /* max_value */
```